# Terminology for a word containing a prefix/suffix or neither

Tags: suffixes, prefixes, affixes

Does terminology exist for discriminating between words which do/don't contain a prefix/suffix?

How could I describe this difference in the synonyms 'discontinue' and 'stop'? Here, 'dis' is a prefix and 'stop' contains no affix.

More fundamentally, is there a term for words which do not contain other words/affixes as substrings?

I am also curious if a word contains an affix vs another word as a substring, if these are different concepts.

Comment: Where you wrote "which do not contain substrings of other words", did you mean to say something like "which do not contain other words as substrings"?  Are you counting an affix as a type of word, by the way?

Comment: That is what I meant @snailboat I'll update the question. I'm not sure if affixes can be words. Maybe I'm asking 2 questions. Is there a term for a word which contains no affix? And, is there a term for a word which contains no other words as a substring?

Comment: What a great question !!  Surely there are technical terms here??  (like ...... "singleton word" or some such??)

Comment: Are there any words which are composed of only a prefix and suffix?!

Comment: @JoeBlow _enable_, _unity_

Comment: Is linguistics.stackexchange.com a better place for technical questions like this?

Comment: @Barmar Good examples if you're talking about substring matches, but etymologically I don't believe either of those is made entirely of affixes.

Comment: @snailboat I knew that, it was kind of a flippant reply. I don't know if they're real words, but perhaps something like _re-ing_, the act of prefixing a word with _re_ (and similar words could be created for most other prefixes and suffixes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is an addition to @user2655010's answer as I don't have commenting privileges*

According to [this definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/root) a root is `a morpheme that underlies an inflectional or derivational paradigm`.

And since a [morpheme](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/morpheme) is: `any of the minimal grammatical units of a language, each constituting a word or meaningful part of a word, that cannot be divided into smaller independent grammatical parts` then a root would not contain another word or affix

Answer (score 0):

What about describing "stop" as a *root* word and "discontinue" as a root with a prefix? http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~kemmer/Words/rootaffix.html talks about dividing morphemes into roots and affixes.

Comment: Would a root necessarily not contain a another word or affix? Or is this a relative term?

Answer (score -3):

The most likely option would be root words

Comment: Please explain why you think this.